# How to apply lower() to pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

What's the correct way to lowercase all text-like columns in a pandas dataframe? I was trying this approach

```
def lowercase(col):
    if isinstance(col, __pandas_object_type__):
        return col.str.lower()
df = df.apply(lowercase)
```

where `__pandas_object_type__` is just a placeholder to identify object types or string types. I know for date and times that would be something like `pd.DatetimeIndex` but I can't find the right alternative for my case.

Thanks for your help

Comment: df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).apply(pd.Series.str.lower,axis=1))

Comment: @WeNYoBen This would fail on columns that are of mixed python types, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PMende I am not sure about the mixtype in his real data or not , and if the data have mixed type,  for data safety purpose we should downgrade the dtype.

Comment: @WeNYoBen I just checked. Your method fails explicitly. Mine fails silently: it turns mixed `str`/numeric columns to columns with `str` and `NaN` in the column where there used to be numerics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try each column and pass if it fails:

```
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[col] = df[col].str.lower()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

This way, you avoid the explicit type checking.

Warning: this will take mixed-type columns that have strings in them, and replace non-string entries with `NaN`.